# Error TS2349 when using union typing (boolean and function)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class on which there is a "isVisible" property, which can be either a boolean or a function which returns a boolean.

The following code shows what I am currently using, which runs fine, and does what I want, but keep getting `error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.` on compilation.

```
export class Foo {
    isVisible: boolean | ((bar?: any) => boolean);

    constructor(isVisible: boolean | ((bar?: any) => boolean) = true) {
        this.isVisible= isVisible;
    }
}
```

The idea is that when I am evaluating the instances of `Foo`, I do the following to determine if each one is visible:

```
public isVisible(item: Foo) {
    if (typeof item.isVisible === 'boolean') {
        return item.isVisible;
    }

    return item.isVisible(this.thing);
}
```

Edit:
The compilation error message references the last line in the code block above (i.e. `return item.isVisible(this.thing);`).

The error itself is generated from the gulp typescript plugin when I run my build task.

Edit 2:
It turns out this may be because I'm actually still using TypeScript 1.8 - I'll try upgrading to 2.x and see if that fixers the issue.

Comment: Where's the error? I can't reproduce that in playground

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `:boolean` at the end of your method signature:

```
public isVisible(item: Foo):boolean {
     if (typeof item.isVisible === 'boolean') {
         return item.isVisible;
     }

     return item.isVisible(this.thing);
}
```

The error is complaining about the signature, not returning a `boolean`. Adding `:boolean` will tell that the method is returning a `boolean`.